# Overriding protected methods in Java

Tags: java, methods, overriding, protected

Test.java

```
package a;
import b.B;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] v) {
        new A().test();
        new B().test();
    }
}
```

A.java:

```
package a;
public class A {
    protected void test() { }
}
```

B.java:

```
package b;
public class B extends a.A {
    protected void test() { }
}
```

Why does `new B().test()` give an error? Doesn't that break visibility rules?

`B.test()` is invisible in `Test` because they're in different packages, and yet it refuses to call the `test()` in `B`'s superclass which is visible.

Links to the appropriate part of the JLS would be appreciated.

Comment: "give an error" .. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Kevin he's asking why he can't call a method that he has access to the super method of.

Comment: @Jeremy: it refuses to compile: "a/Test.java:10: test() has protected access in b.B"

Comment: @Kevin: Read the question: "doesn't that break visibility rules?"

Comment: @Jeremy the error is (in this case) fairly obvious: it's a compile time error saying `B().test()` isn't visible to `a.Test.main(String[])`.

Comment: @glowcoder: well, I can do that by casting to the superclass. The real problem is that class Test should not know that class B has overriden method test(), because it is invisible to it.

Comment: @Crom I have to admit, the first thing that ran through my head is "Ah, another new Java programmer who needs to learn how the `protected` keyword works." Then as I went to gather evidence for my case, it fell apart on me, and I'm completely baffled (as a Java programmer of 7 years.)

Comment: @Crom I don't believe it's supposed to be invisible. There's a difference between the literal meaning of "invisible: you can't see it" and the java meaning of "invisible: you know it's there but we're not letting you play with it."

Comment: Think of it this way: if it couldn't see it, how would it know whether or not it could call it or not?

Comment: @glowcoder: yeah, I thought it might be something in the exact meaning of "invisible". Still, I asked because it's a shady enough area that it could be a compiler bug, and if it wasn't a bug, I was hoping someone would have a quick link to the JLS.

Comment: Try compiling it in Eclipse. Then try compiling with `javac`. If you get the same results, it's not a compiler bug (Eclipse uses its own fancy-schmancy compiler, not javac).

Comment: @Matt Ball: I did try both. Yeah, eclipse uses ecj, but is it that far fetched to think they might have the same bug (not that this is a bug)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you go JLS on `protected` keyword:
[JLS protected description](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6.2) and [JLS protected example](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6.2).

Basically a `protected` modifier means that you can access field / method / ... 1) in a subclass of given class *and* 2) from the classes in the same package.

Because of 2) `new A().test()` works. But `new B().test()` doesn't work, because class `B` is in different package.

Answer (score 7):

This is just not how inheritance works in Java.

If a method is overridden, and the overridden method is not visible, it's a compile-time error to try and call it.

You seem to expect that Java would automatically fall back to the method in the super class, but that does not happen.

*I'll try and dig out the JLS later on why this is not done...*

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that at compile time you are telling Java that you want to access a protected member of a class when you do not have such access.

If you did this instead;

```
  A a = new B();
  a.test();
```

Then it would work and the overridden method will run because at compile time Java checks that you have access to A. At run time the object provided has the appropriate method so the B test() method executes. Dynamic binding or late binding is the key.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, overriding the protected method is possible.

```
class A{
protected void f(){
SOP("A");
}}
class B extends A{
protected void f(){
SOP("B");
}
public static void main(String...args)
{
B b=new B();
b.f();
}
}
```

Output: B